# Calculate slope for linear interpolated movement

Tags: c++, mathematics, vector, sdl

I want to move rectangles to their targets the "smooth" way with linear interpolation. I hope this is right.

```
float slope(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2) {
    return std::abs((y2 - y1)) / std::abs((x2 - x1));
}

int s = slope(x, target->x, y, target->y);

if(x > target->x) {
    x -= s * speed * delta;
} else if(x < target->x) {
    x += s * speed * delta; 
}

if(y > target->y) {
    y -= s * speed * delta;
} else if(y < target->y) {
    y += s * speed * delta; 
}
```

The result is that they barely move. But when they move it is very slow or fast as hell.
I would also apreciate any suggestions on how to reach the target better.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Slope will typically be a real number, but you're casting it to an int - that means any shallow slopes (< 45 degrees) will yield an s of zero, preventing all movement.

Multiplying by slope doesn't make sense here - it makes vertical movements much, much faster than horizontal movements (to the degree that straight horizontal movement will proceed at a speed of zero, and straight vertical movement will proceed at infinite speed)

Try generating a unit vector in the direction of movement, and advancing along that vector proportionate to your speed. That gives uniform speed in all directions.

Comment: Hi thanks. Could you give me example code? Would be nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple solution using a uniform vector:

```
float dx = target->x - x;
float dy = target->y - y;
float dist = std::sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
if (dist > speed * delta) {
    dx /= dist;
    dy /= dist;
    x += dx * speed * delta;
    y += dy * speed * delta;
} else {
    x = target->x;
    y = target->y;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!